# velocity stagger with own function

Tags: javascript, velocity

I switched from anime.js to velocity.js and try to defnine a simple animation with delayed opacity. For this I use the stagger.
But if I put a function for the stagger delay in it, I have no delayed stag animation. every elemenet is popping up but not animated and delayed.
In the first i tried what I have used for the animation with anime.js and the second one is directly from the [github issue](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/169#issuecomment-48786285).

Here is also my jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/firetuh/edit?html,css,js,output

```
var greenElem = $('.pointGreen');
var yellowElem = $('.pointYellow');
var redElem = $('.pointRed');


setInterval(function() {
  greenElem
    .velocity({
      fill: '#5cb83f',
      opacity: 1
    }, { stagger: 
        function(elem, index) {
            return index * 500
        }
    });

  yellowElem
    .velocity({
      fill: '#feb65c',
      opacity: 1
    }, { stagger: 
        function(elementIndex, element) {
            return 1000 * (0.85 - Math.exp(-elementIndex/10));
       }
    });

  redElem
    .velocity({
      fill: '#d43f3a',
      opacity: 1
    }, { stagger: 500 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this could be either an intentional oversight or a bug with velocity. It looks like from the code that `stagger` only works if the first value passed in is a pre-canned effect like `fadeIn` or `transition.slideLeftIn` - it doesn't look like it is supported for other animation types. You could, in theory, achieve this on your own with something like

```
yellowElem
    .each(function(index, element) { 
        $(element).velocity({
            fill: '#feb65c',
            opacity: 1
        },{ 
           delay: index * 500 
        });
    });
```

Also, you will want to change your `setInterval` to `setTimeout`

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your answer and you solution. I think because your expertise I will post a issue on Github. Soemtimes it will help also other people.